# Pretty print llvm-general-pure ASTs as llvm-ir?

Tags: haskell, llvm-ir

I used [llvm-general-pure](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-pure) to build an abstract syntax trees for a program in the [LLVM language](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

Using the [provided pretty printer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-pure-3.4.4.1/docs/LLVM-General-PrettyPrint.html#v:showPretty), I get output that looks like

```
A.Module {
  A.moduleName = "main",
  A.moduleDataLayout = Nothing,
  A.moduleTargetTriple = Nothing,
  A.moduleDefinitions = [
    ...
    A.GlobalDefinition A.G.Function {
      A.G.linkage = A.L.External,
      A.G.visibility = A.V.Default,
      A.G.callingConvention = A.CC.C,
      A.G.returnAttributes = [],
      A.G.returnType = A.IntegerType {A.typeBits = 32},
      A.G.name = A.Name "Main",
      A.G.parameters = ([], False),
      A.G.functionAttributes = [],
      A.G.section = Nothing,
      A.G.alignment = 0,
      A.G.garbageCollectorName = Nothing,
      A.G.basicBlocks = [
        A.G.BasicBlock (A.Name "mainBlock") [
          A.Name "n57" A.:= A.Alloca {
            A.allocatedType = A.IntegerType {A.typeBits = 64},
            A.numElements = Nothing,
            A.alignment = 0,
            A.metadata = []
          },
...
```

I want output that looks like

```
define i32 @main() {
mainBlock:
    %n57 = alloca i64
    ...
}
...
```

It looks suspiciously like there's an [automatically generated parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-quote-0.2.0.0/docs/LLVM-General-Quote-Parser-Parser.html) for the LLVM language in the llvm-general-quote package, but no corresponding pretty printer.

[Stephen Diehl's excellent article](http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/) hints at something called `moduleString`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`llvm-general-pure` doesn't have a pure pretty printer, we have to go through `llvm-general` to do this. It can print out the IR by going through `withModuleFromAST` on the Haskell AST to manifest the Module representation (i.e. the C++ Module) of the IR and then calling `moduleLLVMAssembly` to invoke the pretty printer.

```
moduleLLVMAssembly :: Mod.Module -> IO String
withModuleFromAST :: Context -> AST.Module -> (Mod.Module -> IO a) -> ErrorT String IO a
```

This isn't pure Haskell though, it's all going through the FFI to call LLVM's internal functions.

```
import LLVM.General.Module as Mod
import qualified LLVM.General.AST as AST

ppModule :: AST.Module -> IO ()
ppModule ast = withContext $ \ctx ->
  runExceptT $ withModuleFromAST ctx ast $ \m -> do
    llstr <- moduleLLVMAssembly m
    putStrLn llstr
```

There's no reason we couldn't have a pure pretty printer though and indeed I started on a project to do just this called [llvm-pp](https://github.com/sdiehl/llvm-pp), but it's just a large amount of mind-numbingly boring work to write a pretty printer for the whole LLVM specification.

Comment: I can't find `moduleString` [anywhere on hackage](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahackage.haskell.org+moduleString+LLVM). It appears to have been [in the documentation for 3.3.8.2](http://bscarlet.github.io/llvm-general/3.3.8.2/doc/html/llvm-general/LLVM-General-Module.html) but it's not in [3.4.4.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-3.4.4.1/docs/LLVM-General-Module.html) (the newest version on Hackage with documentation).

Comment: I should have trusted my gut this morning when it said, "write a pretty printer for the subset of llvm you're using, you know you'll be done in a few hours", but my heart derailed me when it said, "you won't be happy with a pretty printer for anything less than the whole spec", and so my mind complained along the lines of, "it's a large amount of mind-numbingly boring work to write a pretty printer for a whole specification".

Comment: Sorry ``moduleString`` became ``moduleLLVMAssembly`` in later versions. They do the same thing, dump the IR to stdout.

Comment: @Cirdec As for the pure pretty printer, it would be great (especially for getting llvm-general into GHC mainline) but, yeah, it's a ton of thankless boring work.

Comment: I added enough to your llvm-pp parser to be able to do what I needed. https://gist.github.com/Cedev/e1ec5526b502a3dbb1a7

Comment: @Cirdec Sent you a note on the Gist on Github about merging the changes.

Comment: @StephenDiehl I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, but I would like to thank you very much for the excellent articles on your website! They are always a great read!